# How can I check if the module output is enabled on the Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, third-party-module

I created a simple verification adding on the admin panel a select to enable or disable, but I want to add a verification to check if my module output is enabled, how can I do that?

Today I'm using this code on my module:

```
public function isEnable(){
    return $this->getConfig('general/enabled');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this verification below.

```
$this->isModuleOutputEnabled()
```

or you can use the method below that also use the method **isOutputEnabled** in the same class.

```
$this->_moduleManager->isEnabled('Magento_Reports')
```

Answer (score 1):

***You can use configuration setting:***

```
 $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
             'advanced/modules_disable_output/' . [ModuleName],
             \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
 )
```

**example:**

```
 $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
             'advanced/modules_disable_output/Magento_Catalog',
             \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
         )
```

---

```
if (!$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'advanced/modules_disable_output/Magento_Catalog',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        )) {
           // output enable
 }else{
   // Disabled Output
 }
```

Comment: Every time 0 coming that means all the time it shows module as enabled. I have made module's output Disabled in all the stores, store-views, websites & Default but still showing 0 as output means module enabled. Any other  solution?