# How to know if module's output is disabled in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, module

I have already tried these solutions : [How can I check if the module output is enabled on the Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174733/how-can-i-check-if-the-module-output-is-enabled-on-the-magento-2)

But the thing is if I use this solution, it always give 0.

```
$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
             'advanced/modules_disable_output/' . [ModuleName],
             \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
 )
```

If I use this solution, it always give 1.

```
$this->_moduleManager->isEnabled('Module_Name')
```

So, I am confused why it is so! I have one module and it's output I have kept disabled from  **Config. -> Advance -> Advance in Default, Main Website, Default Store View.**

And kept Enabled in my custom created Website, Store & Store View so whenever I run `sitename.com` or `sitename.com/mycustomnewstore` it gives the same output either 0 or 1 as per above code.

It should give `1(Disabled) in sitename.com` & `0(Enabled) in sitename.com/mycustomnewstore`

Any other code or technique?

Answer (score 0):

Please try passing the third parameter to **getValue** function. It should be store object of store ID

> $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
>                'advanced/modules_disable_output/' . [ModuleName],
>                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, **[StoreID]**  )

**OR**

Try this

> $this->_moduleManager->isOutputEnabled('Module_Name')

instead of

> $this->_moduleManager->isEnabled('Module_Name')

Comment: Hi Ravinder, thank you for your reply :) but the issue remains same :(